# EJS intellisense autocomplete not working properly on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, ejs, intellisense

I have ejs extensions installed on vscode.

This is how it supposes to work

[image]

But sometimes it not focued on autosuggetion, so I need to press 'arrow down' inorder to access it.

[image]

I want ejs intellisense to accept suggestion on tab.

Comment: Here my vscode settings.json
[link](https://pastebin.com/myk3A6vm)